# Android Memory Leak : InputMethodManager, Bitmap

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, bitmap, out-of-memory

This is kind of weird, I'm able to get rid of my own memory leaks, but I'm not able to do the same in this case.

Image below shows the heap contains Bitmap (like 2.5 MB) which is linked from current Activity (mDecor points to current Activity).

I've tried to remove InputMethodManager instances all over the application, no effect

I've tried setting default state of keyboard (if the bitmap is some kind of sprint drawable for system keyboard), still no effect

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Nothing helped, **is there anything I can do about this?**
Note that the solution is not Android API version specific (I've tested on API 8 and 14/15/16, and all of them have the same issue)

[image: Heap]

---

**Probably a bug, can someone please confirm that?**

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34731
- [Main Activity is not garbage collected after destruction because it is referenced by InputMethodManager indirectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038158/main-activity-is-not-garbage-collected-after-destruction-because-it-is-reference)
- [InputMethodManager holds reference to the tabhost - Memory Leak - OOM Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769748/inputmethodmanager-holds-reference-to-the-tabhost-memory-leak-oom-error)

Comment: I don't know what is causing this on your app.But on my app also I faced the same issue and through hit and trail,I found that I was setting `Typeface` from asset using `Activity Context`,which wasn't being `GC`.But what I want to say that it isn't bug as there is something on your app that is probably triggering it and is not being clearly shown on `MAT`

Comment: might have something to do with edittext if you have one. This link shows the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069501/edittext-causing-memory-leak?rq=1