# Android how to trace memory leak?

Tags: android, memory, allocation, mat

I have an application just like Pulse and its in beta stage
      https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.braindigit.nepal.khabar

I have   a main layout which  holds a `LinearLayout` named `NewsCategoryHolder` and on this layout I dynamically add and remove another layout name `CategoryView` .This `CategoryView` contains `HorizontalListView` and other `views`.
Further for navigation I have implemented `ActionbarSherlock Tab` and on each click of the tab `NewsCategoryHolder` will remove all its views and then add `CategoryView`.
Each `CategoryView` has its own `AsyncTask` to either load data from server or from database.
And on each addition and removal of `CategoryView` I have removed all its views,assigned its adapters to null and even the `Context` it holds to null. But as I navigate from `Tab` to `Tab`,the memory of the application increases. I feel that it is the case of some memory leaking going on my application.
I have gone all the tutorials ,links and videos about `MAT` and other analyzers,but I couldn't pin point the exact portion from which the app is consuming memory or the point on which `GC` couldn't collect the object refrences.

I just want to find the location where memory consumption is high,but couldn't be able to do that.I have attached *.hprof http://news.braindigit.com/saved/android3201806337409456011.hprof file and just want some help on its analysis and my application package name is `com.braindigit.nepal.khabar`

Comment: After removing different classes,views etc what I found is my issue is similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681709/android-memory-leak-inputmethodmanager-bitmap),and I don't know what is the reason behind this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the main reason  why memory consumption is high.Rather than from the `MAT` ,after removing various views from layout and various statements,I found that I am using font from the `asset` folder which was the main culprit.

```
headingText.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), DataHolder.FONT_PATH));
```

So by doing this maybe `Context` is being referenced or `TypeFace` is being referenced and was never `garbage collected`.But removing this line of code fixed all the memory leak issue on my app.

Further this issue can be solved using the technique described here
[Typeface memory leak](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904)